# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when using .reduce

Tags: javascript, axios

```
const sendData = (response, language, locale) => {
  try {
    console.log(response.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.confirmed, 0));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error');
  }
};
```

and my fetch function:

```
const fetchGeneralData = async (param) => {
  try {
    let res = await axios.get(
      `https://localhost/api/${param}`,
    );
      msg.reply(sendData(res.data.results), language, momentLocale);
  } catch (error) {
    msg.reply(language.errorMessage);
    console.error(error, 'Error on fetchGeneralData');
  }
};
```

The `console.log` shows me the correct value but for some reason, I still getting the errors.

I have tried adding `async/await` inside `sendData` but it did not work. My `fetchGeneralData` func works fine when i'm trying to return the date without modify it.

Here is the full message:

```
(node:5500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: t.match is not a function
(node:5500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: response && response .reducer   like that try

Comment: same error @Kasiriveni

Comment: Your function is called `sendData` but you are not calling it anywhere. I do see `sendBrazilData` called though

Comment: Sorry @Phil it was just a refactor mistake. `sendBrazilData` and `sendData` are the same

Comment: What is the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: sorry @Phil, just added to the post

Comment: whats inside res.data.results like?

Comment: array of objects @user9879287. It works just fine if I try to console.log the response in the reduce

Comment: Where is the `t.match()` code? That's what is failing. Is it possible that it's in `msg.reply()`. I ask as you're passing the return value from `sendData()` but that doesn't return anything